# How to "await" the closing of another window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

I have a lot of code looking like that :

```
MyWindow window = new MyWindow(someParam, callingWindow)
```

With a MyWindow class containing something like that :

```
public MyWindow.Processing()
{
`  // Do processing
   ...
   callingWindow.RefreshListBox(); // Listbox for example
}
```

Is there a built-in way to await the closing of the window. I would like to be able to write something like that in the callingWindow's class :

```
await mywindowInstanceCloseEvent; 
RefreshListBoxWhenWindowIsClosed();
```

I wonder if there is an easy way to "pause" a method (whether it's asynchronous or not) until a specific window is closed.

Comment: use `Window.ShowDialog` to block the caller or use `Window.Closed` event.

Comment: Do you mean you want to freeze the parent window or make it inaccessible until your child window is closed?

Comment: ShowDialog is the one ! Thank you a lot. Post it as an answser and I'll accept it. Thanks !

Comment: @ngergo6 Thank you for your comment, no actually I just wanted to prevent further instructions to be executed in the calling window until the new window was closed. ShowDialog() is what I was after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon what is your need. If you need to show the window as modal dialog use `Window.ShowDialog`. Otherwise you can use `Window.Closed` event.

If you want to await it, Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601933/2530848) from @Athari.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource` and `Closed` event for this. Here is a method I use:

```
private Task ShowPopup<TPopup> (TPopup popup)
    where TPopup : Window
{
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    popup.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    popup.Closed += (s, a) => task.SetResult(null);
    popup.Show();
    popup.Focus();
    return task.Task;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
await ShowPopup(new MyWindow());
```

You can replace `Show` method with `ShowDialog` if you want the window to be modal.

If you want to get result from the window, you can modify the code to use `TaskCompletionSource<Result>` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remember that it will surely help me in the future

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Athari
this is so usefull to use it like showdialog on winui :D
Also for create splashwindow

My code for splashwindow using your answer

```
private void Window_Principal_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Activated -= Window_Principal_Activated;
    Terminar();
}
private async void Terminar()
{
    this.Hide();
    await ShowPopup(new Window_CustomSplash());
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32907715)