# WinUI: Diplays SplashScreen with startup logic in OnLaunched method of the Application class

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3

I would like to add some king of splash screen (modal) window in the "OnLauched" method of my WinUI 3 application.

Currently I just instanciate my main window, which is of type 'NavigationRootWindow', as you can see here:

```
    protected override async void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Display splash screen with database check and user login
        // If all is well: Proceed normally
        // If database not available or login failed: Abort with application start / close application


        // Display NavigationRootWindow (main window of the application)
        NavigationRootWindow navigationRootWindow = new NavigationRootWindow();
        m_window = navigationRootWindow;
        m_window.Activate();
    }
```

Before I do that, I would like to do two things (see comments in the first part of the method):

1. Check if the database connection is available.
2. Login the user

This I would like to do in a separate window with a view model and the logic that performs the checks. I am sure I can implement the window with the view model and its logic.

However I am simply not able to display any kind of window / splash screen before I instanciate the 'NavigationRootWindow'. If the login is sucessful, I would need to close the splash screen / login window again, before I instanciate the 'NavigationRootWindow'.
As I understand, I cannot instanciate another 'Window' derived type, because there is only one application window.

Can you suggest an approach to display a splash screen / some modal dialog triggered from within the "OnLaunched" method? The result of this screen shall determine if the application can continue.
I am also open for other suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: i was able to create a splashwindow mixing this post with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601794/how-to-await-the-closing-of-another-window/74012372#74012372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a single window
- Set its `Content` and `DataContext` to the "splah screen"
- Do your initialization stuff while the splash screen is displayed
- Replace the `Content` and `DataContext` of the window with your main content and view model once the initialization code has completed

Something like this:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{

    Window m_window = new NavigationRootWindow();
    m_window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Loading..." };
    m_window.Activate();

    //TODO: login the user...
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    m_window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Welcome!" };
}
```

Comment: This has helped me, thank you. I guess this means that the "splash screen" has the same size as the containing window? In theory, I could set the height and the width of the window to some smaller values as long as it is in "splash screen mode" in order to simulate a smaller splash screen?

Comment: Yes, there is only one window involved.

Answer (score 0):

I modified / extended user mm8's solution.

- In the `OnLaunched` method of my `App` class, I instanciate a `LoginUserControl` which will temporarily replace the content of the window. I remember the original content of the window in a field of the class.
- When the `OnLaunched` method has ended, the user sees the window with the `LoginUserControl` as content.
- My `LoginUserControl` will be closed either with a `UserLoggedIn`
  event or a `UserAbortedLogIn` event.
- In case of an aborted (unsuccessful) login I abort the application start by closing the window.
- If the login is successful I post a `UserLoginSuccessful`
  event to the rest of the application and reset the window content to
  its original content (i.e. the first content the user shall see after logging in).

  ```
   protected override async void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
   {
       // Create NavigationRootWindow (main window of the application)
       NavigationRootWindow = new NavigationRootWindow();

       // Store current content of the window (will be used later after the login)
       _navigationRootWindowContent = NavigationRootWindow.Content;

       // Create LoginUserControl and attach event handlers
       LoginUserControl loginUserControl = new LoginUserControl();
       loginUserControl.UserLoggedIn += LoginUserControl_UserLoggedIn;
       loginUserControl.UserAbortedLogIn += LoginUserControl_UserAbortedLogIn;

       // Set LoginUserControl as content of the window and display the window.
       // In case of a successful login, the content will be replaced later by the original content of the window.
       NavigationRootWindow.Content = loginUserControl;
       NavigationRootWindow.Activate();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Login was aborted.
   /// </summary>
   private void LoginUserControl_UserAbortedLogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       NavigationRootWindow.Close();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Login was successful.
   /// </summary>
   private void LoginUserControl_UserLoggedIn(object sender, UserLoggedInEventArgs e)
   {
       EventAggregator.GetEvent<UserLoginSuccessful>().Publish(e.LoginSuccessfulResult);

       // Restore window content to original content
       NavigationRootWindow.Content = _navigationRootWindowContent;
       NavigationRootWindow.Init();
   }
  ```